# Electronic density of Hooke atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, atoms, normalization

[Hooke's atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_atom) has the following wave function:

$$\Psi( \boldsymbol{r_1}, \boldsymbol{r_2}) \propto \left( 1 + \frac{|\boldsymbol{r_1} - \boldsymbol{r_2}|}{2} \right) \exp\left(-\frac{(r_1^2+r_2^2)}{4}\right).$$

Question: How to calculate electronic density $\rho (\boldsymbol{r_1})$ using this wave function?

The answer, which should contain Error function, is on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_atom) but not method.

Aso according to [article linked on wikipedia](http://www.chem.purdue.edu/kais/paper/ref19.pdf), the answer should contain Error function. However Mathematica does not yield this result upon carrying out above integral. Where is my mistake?

Comment: It's derived here, I think, but costs $4 to rent http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/99/1/10.1063/1.465765

Comment: Hi @CountTo10, I think integration is OK (Mathematica!). However, I do not know the definition of $\rho(r_1)$ the quantum chemistry people use.

Comment: Hi, I scoured and stalked the Web,  and got vague references and hints, but somewhere on a pdf file, somebody has it all worked out. I forgot about Mathematica. Would I pay  $40 dollars to buy a paper, not  so much.

Comment: Also here: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/60359/4945

Comment: Must be a typo in that paper. Both should be giving the same results up to a minus sign since you integrate $\vec{r}_2$ over all space. What answer did you get using your expression?

Comment: @Jan Bos Am I doing the correct integral?

Comment: I assume you need to use the wave functions given in equations (4) and (5) of the Kais paper you linked to. Looking at it the expression it should give these error functions.  About the integral you added in your edit I doubt spherical coordinates are useful. The $\vec{r}_1$ defines a direction.

Comment: @JanBos Yes, it is the same wavefunction as the Kais paper Eq. (4) wavefunction. I am unsure as to what would be be a better choice of coordinate system to do such an integral, although I agree spherical coordinates are not working well. Can you suggest one to me?